# Javascript/Angular download method is only downloading 1kb

Tags: javascript, angular, amazon-web-services, observable

I have have a secure AWS url that should return a file for download. However, the downloaded file is only 1kb in size. When I view the "preview" in the inspectors "network" tab for that call I see the image. Just when the result is downloaded it's basically no file at all. The download functionality happens after the http request is subscribed to:

```
  downloadFile(file: string) {
    this.awsService
      .getDownloadUrl(file, poNumber, client)
      .pipe(takeUntil(this.unsubscribe))
      .subscribe(resp => {
        if (resp && resp.url) {
          this.awsService.downloadFile(resp.url).subscribe(data => {
            const navigator = this.window.navigator;
            const isIE = /msie\s|trident\//i.test(navigator.userAgent);

            if (isIE) {
              navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(data.Body, file);
            } else {
              const blob = new Blob([data.Body], { type: data.type });
              const link = document.createElement('a');
              link.href = this.window['URL'].createObjectURL(blob);
              link.download = file;
              link.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent('click', { bubbles: true, cancelable: true, view: this.window }));
            }
          });
        }
      });
  }
```

No errors in the console or api response.

Comment: You typically don't have nested subscribes you normally use a flattening operator like (merge/concat)Map. That could be a cause

Comment: @Nico that wasn't the issue but thanks for the clean up suggestion. This is legacy code so the old dev didn't do that like they should have.

Answer (score 0):

For me the issue was `const blob = new Blob([data.Body], { type: data.type });` I didn't need to use `data.Body` as the value needed was `data` already and `Body` didn't exist in the object. Apparently this request didn't trigger a runtime error even though `Body` didn't exist in the object.